# Error:1046 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was creating a website for myself using MySQL and PHP.

Querying yields the following error:

```
Error:1046 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

All solutions from my research on `Error:1046` failed to solve the issue.

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE  BKMUV (MVNM VARCHAR2(30), LIKES VARCHAR2(30), THETR VARCHAR2(30), CITY VARCHAR2(30);

CREATE TABLE  CUMV (CMV VARCHAR2(30), UMV VARCHAR2(30);

CREATE TABLE  SEAT (DATE1 VARCHAR2(30), BOOKED VARCHAR2(30), USERNAME VARCHAR2(30), MVNM VARCHAR2(30), CITY VARCHAR2(30), CLASS VARCHAR2(30);

INSERT INTO BKMUV VALUES((yeh jawani hai diwani,90,ANSAL,Greater Noida),(fukrey,50,spice, Noida),(Raanjhna,80,INNOX,Delhi));

INSERT INTO CUMV VALUES((images/fukrey.jpg,images/ce.jpg),(images/ranj.jpg,images/dhoom.jpg),(images/yjhd.jpg,images/gc.jpg),(images/gc.jpg,images/bmb.jpg));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in your query:

**Issue 1:** You are using incorrect datatype.(*Assuming it as MySQL which it looks like from the error*) There is nothing like varchar2(It is in *Oracle*.) in MYSQL. You can better use varcghar.

**Issue 2:** You need to put the values of varchar inside `''` when you are inserting in the database.

**Issue 3:** You are missing the closing brackets in your Create table query.

**Issue 4:** (Its more of a suggestion) When you are storing dates then it is good to store them using the date datatype and you should avoid storing dates in varchar.

So it should be like

```
CREATE TABLE  BKMUV (MVNM VARCHAR(30), LIKES VARCHAR(30), THETR VARCHAR(30), CITY VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE  CUMV (CMV VARCHAR(30), UMV VARCHAR(30));

CREATE TABLE  SEAT (DATE1 datetime, BOOKED VARCHAR(30), USERNAME VARCHAR(30), MVNM VARCHAR(30), CITY VARCHAR(30), CLASS VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO BKMUV VALUES('yeh jawani hai diwani','90','ANSAL','Greater Noida'),
('fukrey','50','spice', 'Noida'),
('Raanjhna','80','INNOX','Delhi');

INSERT INTO CUMV VALUES('images/fukrey.jpg','images/ce.jpg'),('images/ranj.jpg','images/dhoom.jpg'),('images/yjhd.jpg','images/gc.jpg'),
('images/gc.jpg','images/bmb.jpg');
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4dfc)**